# How to get the number of unread messages in a topic in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

how can I get the number of unread messages on a message topic in the confluent kafka dotnet?

Comment: At runtime? Or using external cli / admin tools? Getting the **lag** much easier using tools like Burrow

Comment: runtime , thak you

Comment: What if you ran Burrow separately, then called its REST API from c# to get the lag at runtime?